# Scratch score variable doesn't go up

Tags: mit-scratch

I made a shooter game in Scratch, but my score variable doesn't go up when the plane shoots the enemy.

I use a clone for the enemy. The `Score` variable should go up when a `Laser` touches a `UFO1` or a `UFO2`.

What is the problem?

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/947268889/editor/

Comment: The problem is that the code for UFO1 and UFO2 says that it should first glide, and then check if it is touching a laser. But it should be doing both at the same time. Unfortunately I can't tell you how to do that (because I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

I remixed you project.
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/947386913/

Main changes are in "Laser" and "UFO1"

Don't use "glide" block, because you can not do other things during moving.
Use "Forever" block as main loop.

Comment: I want to make the ufo spawn from top and move to down and then move to the left and gone, how to do that?

Comment: like space invader?

Comment: yes, but after go to down it will move to the left side and gone, I already made it like this https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/947459590